# Python Multiprocessing: Signal job completion without passing Event object through a queue

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing

## Problem Outline

I have a python flask server where one of the endpoints has a moderate amount of work to do (the real code reads, resizes and returns an image). I want to optimise the endpoint so that it can be called multiple times in parallel.

The code I currently have (shown below) does not work because it relies on passing a `multiprocessing.Event` object through a `multiprocessing.JoinableQueue` which is not allowed and results in the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Condition objects should only be shared between processes 
through inheritance
```

How can I use a separate process to compute some jobs and notify the main thread when a specific job is complete?

---

### Proof of Concept

Flask can be multithreaded so if one request is waiting on a result other threads can continue to process other requests. I have a basic proof of concept here that shows that parallel requests can be optimised using multiprocessing: https://github.com/alanbacon/flask_multiprocessing

The example code on github spawns a new process for every request which I understand has considerable overheads, plus I've noticed that my proof-of-concept server crashes if there are more than 10 or 20 concurrent requests, I suspect this is because there are too many processes being spawned.

---

### Current Attempt

I have tried to create a set of workers that pick jobs off a queue. When a job is complete the result is written to a shared memory area. Each job contains the work to be done and an `Event` object that can be set when the job is complete to signal the main thread.

Each request thread passes in a job with a newly created `Event` object, it then immediately waits on that event before returning the result. While one server request thread is waiting the server is able to use other threads to continue to serve other requests.

The problem as mentioned above is that `Event` objects can not be passed around in this way.

What approach should I take to circumvent this problem?

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response,
import multiprocessing
import uuid

app = Flask(__name__)

# flask config
app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True
app.config['DEBUG'] = False


def simpleWorker(complexity):
    temp = 0
    for i in range(0, complexity):
        temp += 1


mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
results = mgr.dict()
joinableQueue = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

def mpWorker(joinableQueue, lock, results):
    while True:
        next_task = joinableQueue.get()        # blocking call
        if next_task is None:                  # poison pill to kill worker
            break
        simpleWorker(next_task['complexity'])  # pretend to do heavy work
        result = next_task['val'] * 2          # compute result
        ID = next_task['ID']
        with lock:
            results[ID] = result               # output result to shared memory
        next_task['event'].set()               # tell main process result is calculated
        joinableQueue.task_done()              # remove task from queue


@app.route("/work/<ID>", methods=['GET'])
def work(ID=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':

        # send a task to the consumer and wait for it to finish
        uid = str(uuid.uuid4())
        event = multiprocessing.Event()

        # pass event to job so that job can tell this thread when processing is 
        # complete
        joinableQueue.put({
            'val': ID,
            'ID': uid,
            'event': event,
            'complexity': 100000000
        })

        event.wait()  # wait for result to be calculated

        # get result from shared memory area, and clean up
        with lock:
            result = results[ID]
            del results[ID]

        return Response(str(result), 200)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_consumers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2
    consumers = [
        multiprocessing.Process(
            target=mpWorker,
            args=(joinableQueue, lock, results))
        for i in range(num_consumers)
    ]
    for c in consumers:
        c.start()

    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 8080
    app.run(host=host, port=port, threaded=True)
```

Comment: It seems you are trying to re-invent the `multiprocessing.Pool`. Have you looked into using that? I think it matches this use case almost exactly.